# Run unit tests on multiple databases using Spring and H2

Tags: spring, unit-testing

I have an application that supports multiple databases (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgre). I want to config multiple profiles in Spring to run unit tests on multiple databases (I use H2 as my main memory database). Whenever I run build by maven then it will run all unit tests on multiple databases. Currently I just can run unit tests on one database everytime I build project by maven. How do I config to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a custom JUnit rule:

```
public class MultipleSpringConfigRule implements TestRule
{
    private Object _testObject;
    private String[] _configLocations;


    public MultipleSpringConfigRule(Object testObject, String... configLocations)
    {
        _testObject = testObject;
        _configLocations = configLocations;
    }


    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description)
    {
        return new Statement()
        {
            @Override
            public void evaulate() throws Throwable
            {
                for (String configLocation : _configLocations)
                {
                    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
                        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configLocation);
                    context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(_target);
                    context.start();
                    try
                    {
                        // executes Before methods, current Test method, and After
                        // methods.
                        base.evaluate();
                    } finally
                    {
                        context.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Add the rule to any test class that needs to run against multiple spring configurations:

```
public class MyTests
{
    @Rule
    public MultipleSpringConfigRule _myRule = new MultipleSpringConfigRule(
        this,
        "path/to/mysql/config.xml",
        "path/to/oracle/config.xml",
        "path/to/sqlserver/config.xml",
        "path/to/postgre/config.xml");


    @Autowired
    private MyRepository _myRepository;

    ...
}
```